# JQuery function just call controller action the first time submit button is pressed

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have a JQuery function called `InsertShowStudents()` which is executed correctly every time a submit button() is pressed. On success, I'm calling the other function `GetStudents()` to show the updated list of elements in the table. The `GetStudents()` function just calls the controller action the first time the button is pressed. After that, `InsertShowStudents()` continues inserting in the table but the `GetStudents()` function doesn't invoke the Action Method on the controller.. I've used a breakpoint to prove it, do you know what's happening??

JQuery code:

```
$(function () {
    $("#btnInsertStudent").click(function () {
        InsertShowStudents();
        return false;
    })

})

function InsertShowStudents() {   
    $.ajax({        
        type:"post",
        url: "/Students/InsertStudent/",
        data: { Name: $("#Name").val(), LastName: $("#LastName").val(), Age: $("#Age").val() }
    }).success(function () {        
        GetStudents();
        //clear the form
        $("#myform")[0].reset();
    }).error(function () {
        $("#divGetStudents").html("An error occurred")
    })
}

function GetStudents()
{
    $.ajax({
        type: "get",
        url: "/Students/GetStudents"
    }).success(function (result) {
        $("#divGetStudents").html(result)
    })
}
```

Controller Actions:

```
public ActionResult InsertStudent()
{
    return View();
}

[HttpPost]
//[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult InsertStudent(Student student)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        db.Students.Add(student);
        db.SaveChanges();
        return View();
    }
    return View(student);
}

public PartialViewResult GetStudents()
{
    List<Student> students = db.Students.ToList();
    return PartialView(students);
}
```

Comment: Do you have a cache?

Comment: Which version of jQuery you are using.

Comment: @NiketanRaval jquery-1.10.2.js

Comment: Try adding cache:false to the ajax options for getstudents

Comment: Is the button being replaced when you make your ajax call and update the DOM? (in which case you need event delegation). However all this seems unnecessary and is probably giving worse performance that a normal submit and redirect. Your first call returns a view which you then throw away (and you not even checking if the insert was successful) and you second call is rendered all the data again when all you need to add one row.

Comment: You can simply make one call to `InsertStudent()` and return a value indicating success or otherwise, and in the success callback, just create a new elements based on the values in the form and append them to the DOM.

Comment: @curtainrising you're right, if you want you can post it like an answer and I can give you the point, I thought it was inside the Action Method but after test using different snippets I realized that I needed to set cache:false  to the ajax options for getstudents

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a situation like this where the first time is working I'd assume a cache problem.  To force bypass the cache you can add the option to the ajax request.  For more information check out the [jquery ajax documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/)

```html
$.ajax({
        type: "get",
        url: "/Students/GetStudents",
        cache: false
    }).success(function (result) {
        $("#divGetStudents").html(result)
    })
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
function InsertShowStudents() {   
    $.ajax({        
        type:"post",
        url: "/Students/InsertStudent/",
        data: { Name: $("#Name").val(), LastName: $("#LastName").val(), Age: $("#Age").val() }
    }).done(function () {        
        GetStudents();
        //clear the form
        $("#myform")[0].reset();
    }).fail(function () {
        $("#divGetStudents").html("An error occurred")
    })
}

function GetStudents()
{
    $.ajax({
        type: "get",
        url: "/Students/GetStudents"
    }).done(function (result) {
        $("#divGetStudents").html(result)
    })
}
```

Comment: that one didn't worked, I put an answer with the solution it      seems that the problem was in the Action Method